# How long does it take (in seconds) to burn a fuse with high surge current?

Tags: fuses, surge-protection

Like the title says, how long does it take in seconds to burn a fuse?
Of course it will depend on what type of fuse and the one
I'm using is 61NM 250V/8A but looking at datasheets I could find
on them, they usually have numbers only up to 200% of rated amp.
My question is, would something like a quick surge current of 50A
that last 1 micro second burn the fuse? Right now, there is a surge
protection before the fuse which when I asked the manufacturer should
kick in in few nanoseconds (which seems little too fast to be honest but)
but I'm wondering even with surge control, if a very short duration but
high current could potentially burn the fuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from [this datasheet](http://www.hollyfuse.com/uploadfile/1400750091_7847.pdf): **50A will burn the fuse in 100ms**.

So, 50A for 1µs will not burn the fuse.

[image]

If you're unsure how to read these diagrams, check out [this guide](http://ep-us.mersen.com/fileadmin/catalog/Literature/Application-Guidelines/ADV-P-Application-Information-How-To-Read-A-Time-Current-Curve.pdf).